# Plot bar coordinates along a x axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe such as

```
Seq start end 
S1  20    30
S2  25    35
S3  40    45
S4  41    60
S5  20    60
S6  10    30
```

And I would like to create with **ggplot** a figure such as :
[image]

Where I plot each bar coordinates within the X axis.

There is no preference about the order of the bars within the y axis, but they need to not overlap.

Here is the dput dataframe if it can helps

```
structure(list(Seq = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"), start = c(20L, 
25L, 40L, 41L, 20L, 10L), end = c(30L, 35L, 45L, 60L, 60L, 30L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `geom_segment`:

```
ggplot(data) + geom_segment(aes(x = start,
                                y = Seq,
                                xend = end,
                                yend = Seq),
                                size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Colored by sequences;

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(y = seq, x = start, colour = seq)) +
  geom_segment(aes(yend = seq, xend = end), size = 3) +
  labs(x = "Position", y="", color="Sequences")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(seq = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"), start = c(20L, 
25L, 40L, 41L, 20L, 10L), end = c(30L, 35L, 45L, 60L, 60L, 30L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```